# UIButton does not respond in custom UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell with a UIView "backgroundView" added to TableViewCell contentView. Now, an UIImageView "sharedImage" is added as a subview to "backgroundView".

Here i am adding a UIButton "downloadButton" as a subview to "sharedImage".

I have a selector method for the "downloadButton". But unfortunately the action method is not called for the UIButton.

I have tried changing the UIControlEventTypes, tried changing the UserInteractionEnabled , bringSubViewToFront options but NO LUCK.

Here is the code.

```
        /*Add the background view to the Tableview Cell*/
    UIView *backGroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    backGroundView.frame = CGRectMake(mainViewFrameWidth - widthOfTheBackGroundView - 10.0 , 3.0, widthOfTheBackGroundView, heightOfTheBackGroundView);
    backGroundView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor hs_globalTint] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    backGroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    backGroundView.tag = 101;
    [sendingImageTableViewCell.contentView addSubview:backGroundView];

    NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self.appDelegateInstance getDocumentsPath],mFileInfo.thumbnailPath];

    UIImageView *sharedImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    sharedImage.image = [self getSquareImageByCropping:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath] withOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    sharedImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    sharedImage.tag = 102;
    [backGroundView addSubview:sharedImage];

    sharedImage.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, widthOfTheImageView, heightOfTheImageView);

UIButton *uploadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
uploadButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
uploadButton.selected = YES;
uploadButton.enabled = YES;
uploadButton.tag = indexPathOfTheImageCell.row;
uploadButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[uploadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickOfUploadButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backGroundView addSubview:uploadButton];
```

Read about the responder chain documentation but couldn't figure about problem. Can anyone please let me know if I am going wrong here?

Comment: you need `UIControlEventTouchDown`? if you need tap action should use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Answer (score 1):

You configured your UIButton with `uploadButton.enabled = NO;` You may change this to YES. 
According to Apple s GUI guideline a UIButton should have a minimum height/ width of 44.0f -otherwise the user might not be able to tap it.

Comment: I have enabled the button to YES. But no luck.